# Including Modules in Ruby-Processing Classes/Sketches

Tags: ruby, processing

When I attempt to include a module into a Ruby-Processing sketch, it returns the following StackOverflowError:

```
matt$ rp5 run cylinder_test.rb
matt$ Error: Your application used more stack memory than the safety cap.
Specify -J-Xss####k to increase it (#### = cap size in KB).
Specify -w for full StackOverflowError stack trace
```

Running the sketch with -w provides no additional information.

The module, Cylinder, includes the **Processing::Proxy** module in order to access begin_shape and end_shape methods, among others. I've tried defining the methods as both class methods and instance methods (with and without "self." preceding the method definition).

```
module Cylinder
    include Processing::Proxy
    def self.cylinder( sides, r1, r2, h )
...
```

I have tried removing the "include Processing::Proxy" line, but it just tells me there are undefined constants and methods, which are included in Processing::Proxy. So that's probably not the problem.

The header of my sketch looks like this:

```
class CylinderTest < Processing::App

    load '../controllers/branch_controller.rb'
    load '../controllers/node_controller.rb'

    require 'Cylinder.rb'
    include Cylinder
...
```

I should point out I'm confident the methods work, because when I wrote the Cylinder module itself as a Ruby-Processing sketch, it ran perfectly.

I am using Ruby-Processing 1.0.11, and Ruby 1.8.7.

So, how can I include the Cylinder module without causing a stack overflow error?